# Rotating an arrow towards a fixed point (clock like animation)

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, sprite-kit, game-engine

I want to rotate this arrow across a fixed point in clock. The code below doesn't do what i intend to do, it rotates the whole arrow towards a center of a circle. I also tried to animate it across a circular path but it didn't give me the effect i want ...
i want this arrow to rotate around a circle while the arrow head is pointed towards the center of this circle

```
-(void) addArrow2:(CGSize)size{
    _Arrow2 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"arrow2"];
    _Arrow2.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2 , self.frame.size.height/2 +30);
    SKAction *rotate = [SKAction rotateByAngle:M_2_PI duration:1];
    SKAction *forever = [SKAction repeatActionForever:rotate];

    _Arrow2.yScale = 0.45;
    _Arrow2.xScale = 0.45;

    [self addChild:_Arrow2];

    [_Arrow2 runAction:forever];
}
```

Comment: Why did you unaccept my answer? Any problems you got?

Comment: it is not like the effect in the animation you posted

Comment: Could your explain in details?

Comment: the whole arrow moves not like in the GIF

Comment: Edit your question to show me your issue.

Comment: i want the code you did to make the arrow animate exactly like the gif but it doesn't i copied and pasted your code but it gave me a different effect

Comment: Paste your arrow image here.

Comment: i solved it adding an imaginary radius and used the normal skaction rotate method , thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose your got this kind of arrow →. Change the `anchorPoint` as (1.0, 0.5) and make the arrow follow a circle path. Make some change to fit your need.

```
- (void)addArrow2
{
    _Arrow2 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"arrow2"];
    _Arrow2.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2+30);
    _Arrow2.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.5);
    _Arrow2.yScale = 0.45;
    _Arrow2.xScale = 0.45;

    // Make a circle path
    CGMutablePathRef circle = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGFloat centerX = self.frame.size.width/2;
    CGFloat centerY = self.frame.size.height/2;
    CGFloat radius = 25.0;
    CGFloat startAngle = 0.0;
    CGFloat endAngle = 2*M_PI;
    CGPathAddArc(circle, NULL, centerX, centerY, radius, startAngle, endAngle, true);
    CGPathCloseSubpath(circle);
    SKAction *followPath = [SKAction followPath:circle asOffset:NO orientToPath:YES duration:2.0];

    // Infinite rotation
    SKAction *forever = [SKAction repeatActionForever:followPath];
    [_Arrow2 runAction:forever];

    [self addChild:_Arrow2];
}
```

**Animation preview:**

[image]

Comment: @MohamedAbouGhazala Which circle do you mean?

Comment: i want this arrow to rotate around a circle while the arrow head is pointed towards the center of this circle

Comment: i made a better sketch for it sorry

Comment: One easy way to make the increase the radius of the inner circle (without changing the code you have) is to add some empty space to the "arrow2" image file.

Comment: shinigami i tried this but it is not that accurate though